# How to disable included script in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have included some JS's to my CE(Chrome Extention)

```
"content_scripts": [ {
      "js": ["jquery-latest.min.js", "sample.js"....
    //....
```

How to disable `sample.js` by clicking on a checkbox in `popup.html`?

What Chrome API method should I use to stop executing `sample.js`. I don't want to use it until I click checkbox again.

Comment: Once it is included it is "in memory". You'll need to either prevent it from being included and only include it on the checkbox press, or inside it have something to confirm the status of the checkbox.

Comment: @PaulS. So how to include script by checking checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be conditionally included, then don't include it in `manifest.json`. 
Use [executeScript](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) instead.

```
if(document.getElementById("checkbox-id").checked == true) 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "sample.js"});
```

This is what is called [programmatic injection](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi)